# Some of the epics are shown on the active Sprint view, I'm not able to remove them

Tags: jira, sprint-backlog, epics

For some reason some of the epics are displayed as swimlanes on active Sprint view. Board filter, sorting config are fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'epics are displayed as swimlanes'. Do you mean that when you add a new epic, a new column is automatically added to your board?

Answer (score 1):

JIRA has several options for how you display swimlanes, one of which uses epics.

You can change to a different type of swimlane if you want, or turn swimlanes off all together.

The configuration for this is found under board settings. [More details here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/configuring-swimlanes-764478010.html).